# Nested List "Back" button overlapping toolbar title?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have created a nested list. When the text of the selected item is quite long than back button overlaps the toolbar title.
Is there any way to align toolbar text to right or set font size??
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only "Back" (or something else) for the back button. You just need to add this config in your nested list: `useTitleAsBackText: false` (It is `true` by default).

Else, you can reduce the font size for both button and toolbar title in your CSS file. Like this:

```
.my-nested-list .x-toolbar .x-button-label,
.my-nested-list .x-toolbar .x-title {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```